# Can AC in-rush cause problems for other devices on same circuit?

Tags: power-supply, ac, transient

I'm working with a system that is encountering hardware faults in the field (micro-controller circuits appear to be damaged in some non-visible way); the symptoms are such that it's likely some condition at the site is causing damage to the hardware, since replacing electronics fixes the issue, it doesn't fail when operated away from the site, then fails again within a week or two of returning to the site.

Is it possible that AC power conditioning issues could damage electrical components in the system?  One device of note at the site is a centrifuge that can pull a 100A in-rush current (at 220V) for up to 1 second, followed by continuous operation at up to 30A.  I've heard of power surges causing issues with electronics, so is it possible that a 100A in-rush on the AC power supply circuit could cause damaging surges to other components on the same supply circuit?  I would think that the AC-to-DC power supply for the electronics would protect against this?

Comment: it depends on your PSU, without this detail it is difficult to find some conclusion.

Comment: How long is the cable to said centrifuge and what else is connected in paralell to it at end of the same? Draw a diagram.

Comment: I have very limited information (I'm a software guy who was originally brought in on the theory that it might be a software problem), but glad to have questions I can use to help diagnose further.  My main question was whether it's even conceivable this could cause issues.  I'll see if I can get the PSU specs.

Comment: Brownouts are bad and overvoltage conditions are bad.

Comment: What you need to do is to ask your hardware buddies to present high-time-resolved voltage traces on every power rail and every digital pin that goes into the microcontroller when the centrifuge is starting/stopping, relative to ICs local ground pad/pin. Then go from there. I am sure you will find V-in-max violations for the period of power surges, something like negative voltages in excess of clamping diodes thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that transient voltages associated with starting and stopping the motor could cause problems. The power supply filtering for the electronic system should protect it from most transients on the power lines.

The first thing that I would look at is the routing of any input and output wiring for the electronic system. If any of that wiring is in the same conduit with motor power and control wiring that could easily cause problems. If the electronic I/O wiring is not in metal conduit and close to other wiring that is not in conduit, that could also cause problems.

Also any wiring or electromechanical control components in the same enclosure with electronic control equipment can cause problems.

All enclosures and metal conduits should have protective earth ground connections that are not shared with motor and motor control grounding connections.

There are a lot of possibilities.

Grounding and separation of electronic equipment wiring from power equipment wiring should be covered in the installation instructions for the electronic equipment. You should carefully read the installation instructions and inspect the installation to see if they have been followed.